# How to invoke lambda function in android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

So i made this lambda function, and in that function I made an if statement, which creates me a user in a user table in dynamoDB. How do i call that ONLY call that if statement in my lambda function from android?

Here is my lambda function

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) 
{
    console.log('stageA');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, '  '));
    var responseCode = 200;
    var userTableName = "usersTable";
    var requestBody = event.body;
    var pathParams = event.path;
    var httpMethod = event.httpMethod;  // HTTP Method (e.g., POST, GET, HEAD)
    //User parameters
    var displayName;
    var email;
    var fbUserID;
    var firstName;
    var folders;
    var lastName;
    var origin;
    var profileImageRef;
    var level;
    var username;
    var birthdate;
    var experience;
    var folder;


    if (pathParams == "/user/createByEmail" && httpMethod == "POST") 
    {
        console.log('create by email action');
        requestBody = JSON.parse(requestBody);
         //Set variables
        firstName = requestBody.firstName;
        lastName = requestBody.lastName;
        email = requestBody.email;
        username = requestBody.username;
        experience = "0";
        birthdate = requestBody.birthdate;

        dynamodb.putItem(
            {
                "TableName": userTableName,
                "Item" : 
                {
                    "displayName":{"S": username},
                    "email":{"S": email},
                    "firstName" : {"S" : firstName},
                    "folderNames" : {"M" : { 
                        "My Cards": {"N": "0" } 
                                    } },
                    //"folders" : {"M" : {"My Cards": {}}},
                    "lastName" : {"S" : lastName},
                    "experience" : {"N" : experience},
                    "username": {"S": username},
                    "birthdate": {"S": birthdate}
                }
            }, 
            function(err, data) 
            { if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    context.done(err);
                } else {
                    var response = 
                    {
                        statusCode: responseCode,
                        headers: 
                        {
                            "x-custom-header" : "custom header value"
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(username)
                    };
                    console.log('great success: %j',data);
                    context.succeed(response);
                }
            });
    }
```

And in android, i made an interface which will be called in an AsyncTask to call my lambda function:

```
  public interface MyInterface {

        /**
         * Invoke lambda function "echo". The function name is the method name
         */
        @LambdaFunction
        String user(String userEmail);

        /**
         * Invoke lambda function "echo". The functionName in the annotation
         * overrides the default which is the method name
         */
        @LambdaFunction(functionName = "myUserAPiFxnName")
        void noUser(NameInfo nameInfo);
    }
```

I am new to AWS and lambda, and really hope for your guide. I am not sure if i am doing this write, and hope someone has a clear cut way with steps!

Cheers!

Comment: that looks like javascript to me. not lambda function

Comment: in lambda you use javascript to write the functions

Comment: you can use java, javascript, python, and I think .NET now,  or whatever else you can fit in your 50mb payload and execute from one of those ( ruby, go,  etc can be included in zip and executed )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems as though you would use Cognito to map user identities to IAM roles providing temporary access privileges to call the function directly.  I'm not using cognito in production, nor developing Android, but my cognito does two things for you: one, it provides authentication and authorization with many federated identity services ( facebook, google, saml, oath2, etc ), and two, it provides a user access model so you don't have to program one yourself.  you can pull displayName, email, birthdate from the identity service, and not have to handle logins.  You can go straight to the part where you make your program.

You'd configure an identity pool in cognito and attach some identity provider(s), and invoke apis of first the identity providers and then AWS.  Finally, your application would be able to invoke the lambda functions you write.

Not knowing anything about android, I'd guess there was some user identity you already had access to, probably a google identity.

Comment: yeah i already have cognito working and creating users, but i have my own user table in dynamoDB that i want to add to, modify, or pull data from, and i wanted to know how to go from app -> lambda -> dynamoDB to put data and vice versa for grabbing data.

Comment: invoke the lambda api to execute your lambda.  The cognito pool will have to have access to the lambda, and enough information about the user should be exposed to the lambda through its context parameter to figure out who it is.

Comment: well, not just for users. If i make a "car" object in android and then i want to store it and retrieve from the dynamoDB, how would i call a lambda push method to accomplish that? Basically, I want the getting and sending logic in a lambda function in a push method (like above) and call that lambda function push method from android

Comment: Maybe i should be asking, what do you mean , "ONLY all that if statement" ?

Comment: sorry, to clear up. Going away from user stuff, and trying to make a simple example. 1. i create a "car object". I make a call to the lambda function and pass in the car object. 2. Inside the lambda function i have `if (pathParams == "/car/createCarInDynamoDB" && httpMethod == "POST") 
    {...` and in side there i have code that will take the car object and put it inside dynamoDB. 3. Im in my app, i call the same lambda function except this time i call `if (pathParams == "/car/getCar" && httpMethod == "POST") 
    {...` which returns a car object from dynamoDB to android.

Comment: thats essentially what i want to do with my user object, or any other objects i make.

Comment: you want to call the lambda from android?  And you already have a cognito identity, right?  Just call the lambda with the aws lambda api.  Right?  What am I missing?  As far as httpMethod and inputParams, you're just making those up right?  You can pass whatever you want

Comment: yep i have cognito identity all taken care of. So i guess more specifically, i set up the lambda api in android, but when i call the lambda function using the lambda api it doesnt run the `if (pathParams == "/car/createCarInDynamoDB" && httpMethod == "POST") {...` and thats where my operations are done.

Comment: can you please rephrase your question, i didnt quite understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131109/discussion-between-dan-farrell-and-theq).